# Report Server OData 401 Unauthorized

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I recently upgraded to the October 2017 release of Power BI Report Server.  Now when I try to access things like subscriptions or parameters on a report, I get the message `Something went wrong. Please try again later.`  When I open up the developer console, it shows a `500 Internal Server Error`.  When I use a network monitoring tool like WireShark, I also see a `500 Internal Server Error`.  When I view the actual log files on the report server install directory, it shows the following exception.

```
ERROR: OData exception occurred: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.WebException:
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of:

- Alternating between NTLM, Kerberos, Negotiate
- Updating all credentials in the configuration manager (includes service & execution account - and yes, I backed up and restored encryption key)
- Restarting server, restarting service, clearing cache, deleting temp internet files, accessing via fully qualified domain name (FQDN), accessing via local address, accessing via local server, accessing via remote server

I'm running out of patience with this.  I know the features work and that this isn't just some Microsoft bug because I did a test upgrade in a development environment before doing it in production.  It only works in the dev though.

It is difficult to test because not every API call fails with a 401.  In fact, most of them work.  Just a few select calls fail like retrieving subscriptions and parameters.

What can I try next to resolve this?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @The-First-Tiger unfortunately not - I ended up rolling back and haven't revisited it since